# Find the order of $\operatorname {Aut}(C_p^{\oplus n})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

> Let $C_p$ be a cyclic group of prime order $p$. Find the number of the
>   automorphism group of $C_p^{\oplus n}$.

Is this approach correct?

$C_p$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb Z_p,+)$. The automorphism groups of these two are therefore isomorphic. Further, $\mathbb Z_p$  is also a field. So $\mathbb Z_p^n$ is a vector space of dimension $n$ over the field with $p$ elements. So the number of automorphisms of the group $\mathbb Z_p^n$ is the number of automorphisms of the vector space, which is the number of elements in $GL_n(\mathbb F_p)$. For further calculations, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399406/what-is-the-number-of-invertible-n-times-n-matrices-in-operatornamegl-nf) question.

Comment: Why is the automorphism group in the category of $\Bbb Z_p$-vector space isomorphic to the automorphism group in the category of groups?

Comment: That's what I was unsure about..

Comment: You can use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798579/328173) (recall that the category of abelian groups has a forgetful (fully faithful) functor to the category of groups).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873477/endomorphisms-of-mathbb-z-modules-are-the-same-as-those-of-mathbb-f-p-vect