# Is every additive map $R$-linear if $ℤ \to R$ is an epimorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, epimorphisms

**Question.**
Let $R$ be a ring for which the unique homomorphism of rings $ℤ \to R$ is an epimorphism.
Is every additive map between $R$-modules already $R$-linear?

**Context.**
Part of Exercise 1.5.xi in Emily Riehl’s *Category Theory in Context* asks if the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Mod}_R \to \mathsf{Ab}$ is full.
In other words, if every additive map between $R$-modules is already $R$-linear.
The answer depends on $R$.
For example, this property holds

- if $ℤ \to R$ is surjective. This means that $R ≅ ℤ/n$ for some $n ≥ 0$.
- if $R = ℚ$. More generally if $R$ is a localizations of $ℤ$.

Both types of example rely on the fact that $ℤ \to R$ is “surjective enough”.
So I’m wondering if this property holds more generally whenever $ℤ \to R$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798579/348926